# Python problem with select.select io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create small TCP server using method select.
Unfortunetly this line :

`inputready,outputready,exceptready = select.select(input,[],input)`

returns me this error:

```
  File "D:/Python/servertst.py", line 70, in <module>
    s.run()
  File "D:/Python/servertst.py", line 31, in run
    inputready,outputready,exceptready = select.select(input,[],input)
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

Is it any ways to solve it in normal way ?
Thanks for every help

EDIT:

Input is :

```
self.open_socket() 
input = [self.server,sys.stdin]
```

and Function open_socket() is :

````
def open_socket(self): 
        try: 
            self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
            self.server.bind((self.host,self.port)) 
            self.server.listen(5) 
        except socket.error as message: 
            if self.server: 
                self.server.close() 
            print ("Could not open socket: " + str(message) )
            sys.exit(1) ```
````

Comment: What is `input`?

Comment: On Unix-like system (Linux), the underlying `select` function accepts any file, but on Windows it only accept sockets. That means that you cannot select on `stdin` on Windows.

Comment: could u write short example for me ?